# Django forms.PasswordInput() updated my application main password

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, passwords

On my Django app, I have a custom field rendered with the `forms.PasswordInput()` widget. This works as expected from a visual perspective. However, Chrome detects this as a password and then updates this field with the master password that a user might have set on his account on the app. Is there a way to get a `forms.PasswordInput()` field without Chrome messing passwords fields in it?

Answer (score 0):

You must add autocomplete="off" to your password input, either in html like this:

```
<input name="password" type="password" autocomplete="off"/>
```

or in your `forms.py` like this:

```
password = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"autocomplete":"off"})
```

More information can be found in [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion) about this topic.

**Edit**

This is working in my outdated Chrome version but is not supported in most recent versions. You can try the hack described [here](https://adamsilver.io/blog/stopping-chrome-from-ignoring-autocomplete-off/) but I'd rather go with Javascript to reset the form. Below is a jQuery example:

```
$(() => { // document.ready : wait dom to be loaded
    $('[name=password]').val("") // reset value
})
```

Comment: I just tried it, it doesn't work on Chrome, it still updates the field with the password on the user on the app.

Comment: See my edited answer.